# Add __hash__ and __eq__ to imported type (tkinter DoubleVar) to put it in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I imported some class from other modules (in my application it is a tkinter DoubleVar), and would like to use them as a key in a dictionary. But the class does not have `__hash__` and `__eq__` defined, so it does not work.

Is there any way to add those methods? I come from C#, where there are extension methods, but I just looked it up and I did not find a way to replicate that in python.

Example:

```
import tkinter as t 
root = t.Tk()
var_A = t.DoubleVar(root)
var_A.set(10)
bounds = {}  #I need to store the bounds for some optimization algorithm
bounds.update({var_A: [-10, 10]}) #Throws exception : TypeError: unhashable type: 'DoubleVar'
```

**Can I somehow implement hash functionality in an imported type?**

Or do I have to write a wrapper class that allows me access to the `.get()` and `.set()` methods while implementing `__hash__`?

Edit: I will try to explain why I needed to store the bounds: I have an interactive model with fit functionality. The user is able to chose between different algorithms. All my old algorithms (from scipy.optimize.minimize) did not need bounds to work, but since I wanted to implement black box optimization (using [this repo](https://github.com/paulknysh/blackbox/blob/master/LICENSE)) and the algorithm needs bounds, I needed some way to get the bounds of the parameters. But since there are about 40 different parameters and over 1500 lines of code, I was searching for a way to implement this without too much effort. Since all variables (that are parameters for the fit) are stored in self, I wanted to create a kind of "lookup-table" for the bounds. You are right, this is not the proper way to do things, but I found a better solution now anyways. Thank you

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It doesn't make sense to change the meaning of equality for a tkinter DoubleVar, and it doesn't make sense that you would need to pass it to an optimization algorithm, through a dict or not.

Comment: next time please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Running just this code results in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Comment: The key of dict couldn't be changed, but `DoubleVar` didn't.That's why you receive this error.

Comment: And you didn't pass a dict.You are passing a **set** to `.update`.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry, this question was kind of stupid. I solved it by writing a wrapper class for the variables. But @user2357112 supports Monica this does make very much sense in my application, but it is more than 1500 rows of code and did not quite fit in the post. Obviously, you are not to blame, since my example was pretty bad and did not show any application of the dict. Sorry for that

Comment: In C# jargon, *all* Python methods are extension methods. Unless using introspection (e.g. via metaclasses or decorators) adding a method during or after class definition is equivalent.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I did not know that! Thanks! The answer by Jan below makes even more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign methods (including `__hash__` and similar) to existing classes:

```py
# a class without explicit __hash__
class A:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i

a1 = A(1)
print(hash(a1)) # default hash

# define a "free" function ...
def A_hash(self):
    return hash(self.i)

# ... and "binds" it to class A
A.__hash__ = A_hash

a2 = A(1)
print(hash(a2)) # new it has user defined hash
```

EDIT: updated code with initially unhashable object and dictionary test:

```py
# a class without explicit __hash__
class A(list):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i

a1 = A(1)
# print(hash(a1)) # would be TypeError: unhashable type: 'A'

# define a "free" function ...
def A_hash(self):
    return hash(self.i)

# ... and "binds" it to class A
A.__hash__ = A_hash

a2 = A(1)
print(hash(a2)) # new it has user defined hash

d = {a2:1}
print(d)
```

Comment: But that does not allow me to put it in a dictionary, does it?

Comment: This works, but I have already written a wrapper class. Thanks a lot anyways! :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by writing a wrapper class that implements `__hash__` and `__eq__`. The class also stored the variable and provided the `.get()` and `.set()` so I did not need to change all of my code.

Also, I later got rid of the idea of storing the vars in a dict with the bounds, and just stored `from_` and `to` in the wrapper, which makes much more sense anyways